# SQL Server : Group By según condición

Tags: sql-server, sql, transact-sql

agradecere me puedan orientar o guiar como lograr lo siguiente :

Tabla Compras :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado deseado :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debo agrupar las compras, y agregar una columna que me diga si la compra es de un solo cliente(mostrar ese unico cliente) o distintos (mostrar multi-clientes).

Desde ya agradecido cualquier dato, gracias.

Codigo del ejemplo :

```
declare @compras table(id int,compra varchar(100),cliente varchar(100))

insert into @compras values(1,'COMPRA A','CLIENTE 1'),
(2,'COMPRA A','CLIENTE 2'),(3,'COMPRA B','CLIENTE 1'),
(4,'COMPRA B','CLIENTE 1'),(5,'COMPRA C','CLIENTE 1'),
(6,'COMPRA C','CLIENTE 2'),(7,'COMPRA C','CLIENTE 3'),
(8,'COMPRA D','CLIENTE 2'),(9,'COMPRA D','CLIENTE 2')

SELECT * FROM @compras
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes resolverlo de este modo:

```
WITH Cte
     AS (SELECT Compra AS Compra
              , COUNT(DISTINCT Cliente) AS Veces
              , Cliente
                FROM @COMPRAS AS T
                GROUP BY Compra
                       , Cliente),
     Cte2
     AS (SELECT C.Compra
              , SUM(C.Veces) AS Veces
                FROM Cte AS C
                GROUP BY C.Compra),
     Cte3
     AS (SELECT R.Compra
              , CASE
                    WHEN R.Veces = 1 THEN C.Cliente
                    ELSE 'MULTI-CLIENTE'
                END AS Cliente
                FROM Cte2 AS R
                          INNER JOIN Cte AS C ON C.Compra = R.Compra)
     SELECT C.Compra
          , MAX(C.Cliente) as TIPO
            FROM Cte3 AS C
            GROUP BY Compra;
```

En el primer conjunto obtienes las distintas compras por cliente

[image: Resultado primer conjunto]

Luego en el segundo cte, obtienes el número de veces que se ha comprado.

[image: Resultado conjunto 2]

En el tercer conjunto mezclas ambos y haces un case.

[image: Resultado conjunto 3]

Para obtener finalmente el resultado esperado, agrupando las compras.

[image: Resultado final]

[Group by](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/04/group-by-quizas-la-clausula-mas-conflictiva/)

[Cte correlativo](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-2-correlativos/)

Comment: Estás usando demasiados pasos para algo muy sencillo. Tu primer CTE no está contando, solo eliminando duplicados.

Comment: Gracias Javi por tu tiempo y ayuda., funciono perfecto.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías resolverlo así:

```
select  compra,
        case when count(distinct cliente) > 1 
             then 'MULTI-CLIENTE' 
             else max(cliente) 
        end
        from @compras
        rgroup by compra
```

básicamente agrupamos por `compra` y en aquellos casos dónde hubiera más de 1 `cliente` los consideramos como `MULTI-CLIENTE` sino, mostramos el `cliente` usando un `max()` ya que estamos obligados por el `group by`.

Comment: Gracias Patricio, de igual forma obtengo el resultado positivo.

Answer (score 0):

Dejo una respuesta adicional basada en la de Patricio. Básicamente toma en cuenta que si solo hay un cliente, el máximo y el mínimo serán iguales, si no es así son múltiples clientes.

En lo personal, prefiero esta opcion puesto que prefiero evitar el uso de DISTINCT que puede llegar a ser costoso. Aunque no tengo nada que indique que así sea en este caso.

```
SELECT  compra,
        CASE WHEN MIN( cliente) <> MAX( cliente) THEN 'MULTI-CLIENTE' ELSE MAX(cliente) END
FROM @compras
GROUP BY compra;
```

Comment: Gracias Luis, también la query señalada se logra el acometido.

Comment: Felicidades por escoger la respuesta más complicada y posiblemente ineficiente.